# Laravel resource controller's methods behaving strange

Tags: php, laravel

I am a beginner in laravel. When I was working around its resource controller's methods I found that route name the parameter pass in method has strange relationship. please let me explain it:

**Example 1:
In web.php:**

```
Route::resource('users','UsersController');
```

and In Userscontroller.php:

```
public function show(Users $user)
{
   var_dump($user->name); exit; //returning name
}
```

**Example 2:
In web.php:**

```
Route::resource('users','UsersController');
```

and In Userscontroller.php:

```
public function show(Users $users)
{
   var_dump($users->name); exit;  //null i.e. plain object returned 
}
```

**Example 3:
In web.php:**

```
Route::resource('usrss','UsersController');
```

and In Userscontroller.php:

```
public function show(Users $usrss)
{
   var_dump($usrss->name); exit;     //returning name
}
```

**Example 4:
In web.php:**

```
Route::resource('usrss','UsersController');
```

and In Userscontroller.php:

```
public function show(Users $usrs)
{
   var_dump($usrs->name); exit;     //returning null
}
```

> Note: It is applied to other methods too: like edit, destroy etc

So I am so confused and curious that what laravel expect us to set object name passed to resource controller methods. I suppose to initiate object we can give any name but I guess laravel has some restriction for this. I have googled this too but did not get satisfied answer. Please help me to clear this.
PS: My code is not accepting by stackoverflow due to wrong format warning but I have format it rightly so I am posting it as it is.

I dont understand that stackoverflow is for help us in doubts and people downvote so easily. New users account could be block because of this behaviour. please support them.

Comment: i think you cant pass User object in show(), just pass $id in show()

Comment: I dont understand that stackoverflow is for help us in doubts and people downvote so easily. New users account could be block because of this behaviour. please support them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `php artisan route:list` to see a list of the routes generated by `Route::resource()`. You'll see that the name you pass as the first argument is what is used as the parameter name in the generated routes. When you have an argument to the controller function with the same name, that is also type-hinted with an Eloquent model, Laravel will then try to bind the correct model to the route.

If you don't use the same name, Laravel will just inject a new instance of the model (not pre-populated with existing data). This is the plain model you get back, not an instance of an existing record.

As an aside, however, you might also want to consider renaming your `Users` model to be singular rather than plural as it is generally considered best practice.

Comment: Cleared it now.. Thank you